# Upload Empty Strings to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to upload a child nod to a reference to my Firebase Realtime Database, however I'm running into an issue. I'm trying to have my `secondDateAndTimes` and `thirdDateAndTimes` upload as empty strings if they are not filled out, but my `handleConfirm()` will only work if the two are filled out. What do I need to do so the child node uploads even if the two UILabels are empty/not showing? Thank you!

**JobRequest Model**

```
struct JobRequest {
    
    let uid: String
    let fullname: String
    let username: String
    let address: String
    let firstDateAndTimes: String
    let secondDateAndTimes: String
    let thirdDateAndTimes: String
    let timeConstraints: String
    let jobDescription: String
    
    init(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        self.uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String ?? ""
        self.fullname = dictionary["fullname"] as? String ?? ""
        self.username = dictionary["username"] as? String ?? ""
        self.address = dictionary["address"] as? String ?? ""
        self.firstDateAndTimes = dictionary["firstDateAndTimes"] as? String ?? ""
        self.secondDateAndTimes = dictionary["secondDateAndTimes"] as? String ?? ""
        self.thirdDateAndTimes = dictionary["thirdDateAndTimes"] as? String ?? ""
        self.timeConstraints = dictionary["timeConstraints"] as? String ?? ""
        self.jobDescription = dictionary["jobDescription"] as? String ?? ""
    }
    
}
```

**API Service**

```
struct JobDetailCredentials {
    var uid: String
    var fullname: String
    var username: String
    var address: String
    var firstDateAndTimes: String
    var secondDateAndTimes: String
    var thirdDateAndTimes: String
    var timeConstraints: String
    var jobDescription: String
}

// MARK: - CustomerService

struct CustomerService {

static func uploadCustomerAndJobRequest(jobDetails: JobDetailCredentials, completion: @escaping(DatabaseCompletion)) {
        
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        let values = ["uid" : jobDetails.uid,
                      "fullname" : jobDetails.fullname,
                      "username" : jobDetails.username,
                      "address" : jobDetails.address,
                      "firstDateAndTimes" : jobDetails.firstDateAndTimes,
                      "secondDateAndTimes" : jobDetails.secondDateAndTimes,
                      "thirdDateAndTimes" : jobDetails.thirdDateAndTimes,
                      "timeConstraints" : jobDetails.timeConstraints,
                      "jobDescription" : jobDetails.jobDescription] as [String : Any]
        
        
        REF_CUSTOMERS.child(uid).child("job-request-details").childByAutoId().updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: completion)
}

}
```

**RequestJobConfirmationController**

```
lazy var secondDateAndTimeDetailsLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = .black
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-MediumItalic", size: 14)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()
    
lazy var thirdDateAndTimeDetailsLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = .black
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-MediumItalic", size: 14)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()

@objc func handleConfirm() {
        
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ,
              let fullname = fullnameDetailsLabel.text ,
              let username = customer?.username ,
              let address = addressDetailsLabel.text ,
              let firstDateAndTimes = firstDateAndTimeDetailsLabel.text ,
              let secondDateAndTimes = secondDateAndTimeDetailsLabel.text ,
              let thirdDateAndTimes = thirdDateAndTimeDetailsLabel.text ,
              let timeConstraints = timeConstraintsDetailsLabel.text ,
              let jobDescription = jobDescriptionDetailsLabel.text else { return }
        
        let jobDetails = JobDetailCredentials(uid: uid, fullname: fullname, username: username, address: address,
                                              firstDateAndTimes: firstDateAndTimes, secondDateAndTimes: secondDateAndTimes,
                                              thirdDateAndTimes: thirdDateAndTimes, timeConstraints: timeConstraints,
                                              jobDescription: jobDescription)
        
        CustomerService.uploadCustomerAndJobRequest(jobDetails: jobDetails) { error, ref in
            if let _ = error {
                self.simpleAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Unable to upload job details, please try again later.")
                return
            }
            
            let controller = FindEmployeeJobRequestController()
            controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting your `secondDateAndTimes` and `thirdDateAndTimes` inside the `guard`, which will guarantee that the function returns if they're `nil`, move them outside of that guard and optionally bind them:

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ,
              let fullname = fullnameDetailsLabel.text ,
              let username = customer?.username ,
              let address = addressDetailsLabel.text ,
              let firstDateAndTimes = firstDateAndTimeDetailsLabel.text ,
              let timeConstraints = timeConstraintsDetailsLabel.text ,
              let jobDescription = jobDescriptionDetailsLabel.text else { return }

let secondDateAndTimes = secondDateAndTimeDetailsLabel.text ?? "",
let thirdDateAndTimes = thirdDateAndTimeDetailsLabel.text ?? "",

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured what my problem was, I wasn't setting empty strings as the texts for my UILabels.

**RequestJobConfirmationController**

```
lazy var secondDateAndTimeDetailsLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = ""
    label.textColor = .black
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-MediumItalic", size: 14)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()
    
lazy var thirdDateAndTimeDetailsLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = ""
    label.textColor = .black
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-MediumItalic", size: 14)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()
```